# MVC Registration with details

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, controller

I have a bit of a problem, When a user registers on my site they put in email/password then go onto another for for there details, addres etc, however after inputting details and pressing save it flips straight back to the initial login saying "enter email" "enter password" so it doesn't save the customers details only email/password. Here is my controller-

```
// GET: /Account/Register
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Register()
{
    return View();
}

//
// POST: /Account/Register
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email};
        var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            //  Comment the following line to prevent log in until the user is confirmed.
            //  await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent:false, rememberBrowser:false);

            string callbackUrl = await SendEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account");

            ViewBag.Message = "Check your email and confirm your account, you must be confirmed "
                            + "before you can log in.";

            return View("Create");

        }
        AddErrors(result);
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
}


// GET: Create
public ActionResult Create()
{
    return View();
}

// POST: Customers/Create
// To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
// more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "CustomerId,AccountId,FirstName,LastName,Address,City,PostalCode,Country,Phone,Mobile")] Customer customer)
{
    ApplicationUser user = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>().FindById(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId());
    customer.AccountId = user.Id;

    db.Customers.Add(customer);
    db.SaveChanges();

    return View("Index");

}
```

Here is my customer Model -

```
public class Customer
    {
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public string AccountId { get; set; }

        [Key]
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public int CustomerId { get; set; } 

        [Required]
        [StringLength(16, ErrorMessage = "Your name is too long")]
        [Display(Name = "First Name")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Your last name is required.")]
        [StringLength(16, ErrorMessage = "Last name is too long.")]
        [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Address is required.")]
        public string Address { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "City is required.")]
        public string City { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Postcode is required.")]
        [Display(Name = "Post Code")]
        public string PostalCode { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Country is required.")]
        public string Country { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Phone home number is required.")]
        [Display(Name = "Home Telephone")]
        public string Phone { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Phone mobile number is required.")]
        [Display(Name = "Mobile")]
        public string Mobile { get; set; }
    }
```

And my Razor view -

```
@model T_shirt_Company_v3.Models.RegisterViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Register";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <h4>Create a new account.</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Register" />
        </div>
    </div>
}

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

"Create" part to add details - view

```
@model T_shirt_Company_v3.Models.Customer

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Customer</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })


        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Address, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.City, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.City, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.City, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PostalCode, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PostalCode, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PostalCode, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Country, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Country, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Country, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Phone, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Phone, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Phone, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Mobile, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Mobile, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Mobile, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Comment: Have you considered extending the `ApplicationUser` class to include those fields, then include the additional fields both in the form, and in the `Register` action? ie:

`ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email, CustomInfo = model.CustomInfo ... };`

Comment: Would that mean having everything displayed on one page @DrinkBird

Comment: That depends on your implementation, you could split the form in 2 and hide/show the appropriate sections depending on the step using javascript.

About your approach, could you also post the razor markup and Customer code? There's probably something wrong with the model binding.

Comment: @DrinkBird updated my question with the view and Customer Model

Comment: Thanks, could you also include the razor view for the second step? (where the `Customer` data get entered)

Comment: @DrinkBird updated to include, sorry forgot to add that first time

Comment: Update your second step's `BeginForm` helper to include the controller and method properties, eg `@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))`

Comment: Didn't save the Customer Details to the database after creation, just sent me back to the index, any idea why that would happen @DrinkBird

Comment: Put a breakpoint in the `Create` action and check if your model is being populated properly. I suspect that `CustomerId` is not present because it's not included in the form. Word of caution: you shouldn't provide this id through the form because it can be faked and your code can end up changing some other user's details. Instead use `User.Identity.GetUserId()`

Comment: @DrinkBird I put the breakpoints in even after entering Details and pressing send it never picked up my breakpoints for the Create method, only the one with return View()

Comment: If it isn't even picking up that method in the controller it wont save to the db! Why would it be doing that?

Comment: Double check that you have set the correct controller name/action name at `Html.BeginForm`. Also make sure that your routing settings are ok and the action is reachable. Finally remove `[Bind]` from the action and see if it works.

Comment: I think my BeginForm is calling the first Create which just displays the page and not the second one as you can see above that actually saves the Details, how would i fix that @DrinkBird ?

Comment: Since you have decorated your action with `[HttpPost]` and configured your `BeginForm` by specifying the `FormMethod` (`@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))`) there shouldn't be any problem.

Comment: I put breakpoints all over my create and nothing touches it! @DrinkBird

Comment: Unfortunately I can't really see any errors with your code. My next step would be to create a blank solution, recreate the registration steps there and see how it goes.

Comment: Aaaah @DrinkBird its because when a user registers they aren't automatically logged in so there id isn't taken over. Damn, will need to think of a way around,etc letting them add there address later

Comment: Yea I imagined so, I was just curious why the action wasn't getting hit. It should be hit, just with a blank `UserId` property

Comment: Is your code working now?

Comment: @DrinkBird yeah, turns out that was the only reason! I tried logging in and manually going to the page and it worked when I was signed in, just not before.

Comment: @jamiedanq It does work, just not how I expected, but as the code is done, it does work!